# Getting parent index in map iteration

Tags: mule, dataweave

My task is to 'flatten' a 3 level structure into a 2 level structure.

I am iterating the 3 level structure in XML and I am mapping 'Level3' fields to 'Level2' and this is working just fine, but I also need the index of 'Level2' in one of the 'Level3' mappings.

So my problem is "getting the Level2.index() while iterating Level3".

Hope you can help :-)

```
XML structure (IN):
-----------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Level1 xmlns:ns="urn:aaaa:bbbb:cccc">
  <Level2>
    <Level3>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
  <Level2>
    <Level3>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
</ns:Level1>

XML structure (OUT):
-----------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Level1 xmlns:ns="urn:aaaa:bbbb:cccc">
  <Level2>
  </Level2>
  <Level2>
  </Level2>
  <Level2>
  </Level2>
  <Level2>
  </Level2>
</ns:Level1>


Dataweave 2.0 Code:
-----------------------
(payload.ns0#Level1.*Level2.*Level3 map ( level3 , indexOfLevel3 ) -> {
  Level3Index: payload.ns0#Level1.*Level2.index()?? "",
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simples way is to nest to maps and flatten them using the object expansion feature. [Dynamic Elements Doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
Level1: {
    ( //Flatten all Level2
        payload.Level1.*Level2 map ((item, level2Index) -> 
            {
                (//Flatten all the level 3 under level2
                    item.*Level3 map ((item, level3Index) -> {
                        Level3: level2Index
                    })
                )
            }
        )
    )
}
```